# clarification on convergence of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I get the idea if a sequence is convergent then $$|b_n-L|<\epsilon$$  for n>=N.

but I did not get it with series convergence.
$$|\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k|<\epsilon$$
shouldn't it be 
$$|\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k-A|<\epsilon$$

Comment: You are missing some details in your question so it is hard to say, but it is possible that the block you are objecting to is trying to show a series converges by showing its sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: It is either $|\sum_{k=m}^n a_k|<\epsilon$ (i.e. the partial sums are a Cauchy sequence), or $|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k -A|<\epsilon$. In the expression "$|\sum_{k=m}^n a_k|<\epsilon$" I think there is some "for any $m\leq n$ such that ..."

Comment: that makes sense now, thank you @Milly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ and $\displaystyle A=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n$.

Then
$$
\left|\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k\right|=\left|A_n-A_{m-1}\right|=\left|(A_n-A)-(A_{m-1}-A)\right|\leq \left|A_n-A\right|+\left|A_{m-1}-A\right|\leq 2\epsilon
$$
and there is no extra $A$ to add to this.